# Matrix multiplication in Maple

Tags: maple

I have defined my matrix `M` in Maple as follows:

```
M := Matrix(2, 2, [[-a, a], [b, -b]]);
```

Then I want to derive `M^k` in terms of `M`. The answer I am supposed to get is M^k = M*[-(a+b)]^{k-1}. When I enter the command:

```
M^k;
```

I am getting the following undesired output

```
Matrix(2, 2, [[-a, a], [b, -b]])^k
```

How to solve my problem? Picture from my Maple showing what I have tried.

[image]

Comment: What indication did you give Maple to provide your "desired" result instead of the correct result it gave?

Comment: Are you trying to use Maple to derive that formula, or to prove that it holds? Proving it holds for `k` posint is easily done by induction. The `MatrixPower` command can also derive it (albeit with the factor multiplied into `M`).

Comment: @acer I wish to solve `M^k` in terms of `a`, `b`, `k` and `M`. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get such a result:

```
M := Matrix(2, 2, [[-a, a], [b, -b]]):

simplify(LinearAlgebra:-MatrixPower(M,k));

      [           (k - 1)            (k - 1) ]
      [-a (-b - a)         a (-b - a)        ]
      [                                      ]
      [          (k - 1)              (k - 1)]
      [b (-b - a)          -b (-b - a)       ]
```

You can easily show that this equals `M*(-b-a)^(k-1)`.

[edit] It occurs to me that this might be a coursework question, and as such you might be interested in a more step-by-step approach instead of just what result the `MatrixPower` command provides.

Let's diagonalize the Matrix `M`, checking results as we go.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):

M := Matrix([[-a, a], [b, -b]]);

               [-a  a ]
          M := [      ]
               [b   -b]

(evals,P) := Eigenvectors(M);

                          [  a   ]
                [-b - a]  [- -  1]
    evals, P := [      ], [  b   ]
                [  0   ]  [      ]
                          [ 1   1]

Diag := DiagonalMatrix(evals);

                [-b - a  0]
        Diag := [         ]
                [  0     0]
```

Check that `P.Diag.P^(-1)` equals `M`.

```
simplify( P . Diag . P^(-1) - M );

             [0  0]
             [    ]
             [0  0]
```

It turns out that using `Adjoint(P)/Determinant(P)` is slightly easier to use here than `P^(-1)`. But first we'll check they're equivalent, which might be new to you.

```
Adjoint(P);

          [1   -1 ]
          [       ]
          [      a]
          [-1  - -]
          [      b]

detP := Determinant(P);

                 b + a
       detP := - -----
                   b  

simplify( Adjoint(P)/detP - P^(-1) );

             [0  0]
             [    ]
             [0  0]
```

We can also use `denom(detP)/numer(detP)` instead of `1/detP`.

We want `M^k`. But that's the same as,

```
( P . Diag . P^(-1) )^k
```

Now, the "big idea:. If you multiply `P.Diag.P^(-1)` by itself `k` times then you get various instances of `P^(-1).P` in that product of terms. But `P^(-1).P` will just produce the identity matrix. So `(P.Diag.P^(-1))^k` will telescope down to,

```
P . Diag^k . P^(-1)
```

And here `Diag^k` is,

```
Diag^~k;

     [        k   ]
     [(-b - a)   0]
     [            ]
     [    0      0]
```

which is the same as,

```
Matrix([[1,0],[0,0]])*(-b-a)^k;

      [        k   ]
      [(-b - a)   0]
      [            ]
      [    0      0]
```

So `M^k` is the same as,

```
P . Matrix([[1,0],[0,0]])*(-b-a)^k . Adjoint(P)
  * denom(detP)/numer(detP);

   [            k             k ]
   [  a (-b - a)    a (-b - a)  ]
   [- -----------   ----------- ]
   [    -b - a        -b - a    ]
   [                            ]
   [           k               k]
   [ b (-b - a)      b (-b - a) ]
   [ -----------   - -----------]
   [   -b - a          -b - a   ]
```

You could check that that simplifies to the earlier `MatrixPower` result.

We could also rearrange the terms in that last product,

```
P . Matrix([[1,0],[0,0]]) . Adjoint(P) * denom(detP)
  * ((-b-a)^k) / numer(detP);
```

That last product can be made into *two terms*.

The "first term" turns out to be simply `M`,

```
P . Matrix([[1,0],[0,0]]) . Adjoint(P)
  * denom(detP);

         [-a  a ]
         [      ]
         [b   -b]
```

The "second term" is,

```
simplify( ((-b-a)^k) / numer(detP) );

              (k - 1)
      (-b - a)
```

So `M^k` is the same as that first term times that second term, ie. `M * (-b-a)^(k-1)`.